# effective ways of using beamer to present mathematical equations to a technical audience

Tags: beamer, math-operators, presentations

While presenting my work which included mathematical equations, I noticed that I couldn't engage the audience. They seem to be either puzzled or tired with all the equations on the beamer slide. So, I thought of skipping the equations and replacing them with just words explaining what they do. But, this isn't as effective as explaining an equation. So, I'd like to ask if you have some tips for effective presentation of mathematical content to a technical audience especially. How can I use beamer smartly to engage the audience better with my talk and slides?

Comment: Better suited for http://academia.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: `<Humor> Use Comic Sans font? </Humor>`

Comment: @crypto maybe use the animate package to simulate the relationship between input and output variables. The animate manual shows a couple of examples. The scarabaeus is impressive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are the presentation. The slides are only supplementary. If they are not engaging, then you have some room for improvement in the exposition.

No font or color will make your equations more understandable. You might read Till Tantau's mantra in the `beamer` manual.